# Reading ASCII File over Socket to MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, sockets, csv

I have a program in MATLAB that needs to get a CSV file over sockets. I have tried to no avail to get it to actually accept any data. The MATLAB docs say that after opening the TCP socket, you can just call fscanf(socket) to get  the data, but that always times out.

Here is my java code that is sending the file:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
        {
            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.8", 3000);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./channel1.csv"));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            String line = null;
            int bytes = 0;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sending:" + line);
                    out.write(line);
                    bytes += line.length();
                }
            System.out.println("Wrote " + bytes + " bytes");
            out.close();
            s.close();
            r.close();
        }
```

Running this prints the CSV file along with: "Wrote 2085 bytes"

And here is the MATLAB code trying to recieve the file:

```
t=tcpip('192.168.1.6',3000,'NetworkRole','server');
set(t,'InputBufferSize',10000);
fopen(t) %blocks here for connection
data = fscanf(t); %times out here
```

If I connect to the MATLAB script using netcat with the command:

```
nc 192.168.1.8 3000
```

Everything works fine, however if I use netcat to try to send the file:

```
cat channel1.csv | nc -v 192.168.1.8 3000
```

It results in the same as the Java program.

How can I receive an ASCII file in MATLAB?

Comment: Are you sure about where it's blocking or timing out? What's the error message or other behavior you see when your Matlab script times out? `fscanf(t)` with just one argument should error out immediately; it requires an additional format argument at least. And what happens if you use the unrestricted `tcpip('0.0.0.0',...)` form on the Matlab side?

Comment: MATLAB blocks on fopen for sure. According this [document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/writing-and-reading-data_f16-57447.html#btfksnp), fscanf will work with just one argument. The unrestricted tcpip form does not change anything, although is a better way to do it.

Comment: Gotcha; I didn't realize it was a different `fscanf` signature for the `tcpip` object. Based on the doco you linked, I think what may be going on is that `fscanf` isn't meeting its end conditions: under "Reading ASCII data", it says it'll read until a) it encounters a Terminator, b) it fills its buffer, c) it reads the specified number of values. It doesn't mention anything about the client socket closing causing the read to terminate; it may be designed this way to allow collecting data from multiple connections. To test this, try doing `fscanf(t,'%c',500)` and see if it returns some data.

Comment: If that's what's going on, the fix could be to use the `Terminator`: set the `Terminator` property on `t` to 0 (ASCII NUL, which won't appear in real text data) and have your Java client write a `(char) 0` (not the character '0', but an actual all-zeros byte, like with `ostr.write(0)` on the socket's output stream) before closing the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The above MATLAB code works, I added one line to Java to flush the buffer after every write and it worked! So my Java code is below. I am not sure why flushing the buffer helped. It seemed to be something about MATLAB parsing multiple lines from Java at once?

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
        {
            log("Hello World!");

            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.8", 3000);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./channel1.csv"));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            String line = null;
            int bytes = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
                {
                    line = ++i + "," + Math.sin(Math.toRadians((double) i));

                    System.out.println("Sending:" + line);
                    out.write(line + "\n");
                    out.flush();
                    bytes += line.length(

                }
        }
```

Thanks to [Andrew Janke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105904/andrew-janke) for the help!

Comment: It looks like flushing the buffer is not the only change here. You're also adding a `+ "\n"` to the lines that are being written out, and that might actually be fixing it.  Java's `BufferedReader.readLine()`, as in `((line = r.readLine()) != null)` in the original example, strips off the line-ending characters. So I think the original Java code is actually writing one big long un-terminated line (because it's using `write()` and not `println()` on the actual socket), and Matlab's `fscanf` is looking for a \n EOL that never appears. Try adding just a `+ "\n"` to the original code to confirm?

Comment: (Because the buffer should get flushed when you close the socket you're writing to regardless of whether you explicitly call `flush()`.)